# What is this card and what's its purpose?

Tags: graphics, powerpc, logicboard, power-mac

I've come across what appears to be a vintage PCI card for the Macintosh. I've searched everywhere to find out what it is, but so far it's been unsuccessful. It has what appears to be memory sims and at least two FPGAs, but has no external ports, making it unlikely to be a conventional graphics card. It's labeled as PowerShop Mezzanine and possibly made by Adaptive Solutions. The board was copyright back in 1995, placing it around the PPC era of Macintosh machines. Any information on this board?

[image]

[image]

Comment: No answer as yet - data on some components - Xilinx - https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/XC4006.html  PLX 9060 - http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/390078.pdf PNY are a graphics card company (they make the founder's edition NVidia cards)

Comment: Can you unmount that mezzanine daughtercard & see what's under?

Comment: Nice find! I wonder if the drivers are available anywhere still... If you are in need of someone with a collection of PCI PowerMacs and a strong interest in vintage hardware to pawn old junk like this off on, hit me up. ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it!

It's a Photoshop accelerator card.

Google books came up with [this announcement](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=alEdS8humpQC&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=%22adaptive%20solutions%22%20mac%20graphics%201995&source=bl&ots=U1ECbsN78Q&sig=ACfU3U0jCq2ItOHwUk_B9uHivwRLgbALDg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij2_vm8vPtAhXTVsAKHUe4CCIQ6AEwEHoECA4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22adaptive%20solutions%22%20mac%20graphics%201995&f=false) from Computerworld magazine.
Screenshot from there -

[image]

Comment: $3000....! Shame tech doesn't hold its value.

Comment: Nice find. Wow. $3000 in 1995 dollars to speed up what by today's standards is a dreadfully simple version of PS (although I happily used PS 2.0 for many years, I must admit) to what I bet would still seem crawlingly slow compared to what we're used to. Amazing how far we've come.

Comment: It's a PCI card designed for the PowerPC based Macs. While PPC is slow, it's not quite as slow as older x86 or 68K. The performance might be incredibly fast considering the shear amount of hardware thrown at it. There are at least two FPGAs and probably other DSP chips in there. Of course, the rest of the machine is a major bottleneck. It would be interesting to see how it would perform on modern hardware, but that would be quite a task to figure put the interface for it.

Comment: @ATL_DEV You could plug the card into an early Mac Pro but you couldn't run classic Mac OS on it. Maybe a PowerMac G4 or G5 if you really want to play with it.

Comment: @benwiggy If it "held its value", your mobile phone would cost tens, if not hundreds, of thousands of dollars. The card didn't lose value so much as it wasn't, in retrospect, that valuable, just expensive.

Comment: @chepner - not necessarily. A 1924 Bentley will cost you at least half a million pounds. You can get a brand new one for a quarter of that :p

Comment: @chepner I do not really wish for a world where tech held its list price.

Comment: ATL_DEV - adding the nice green tick to the answer would nicely round off the process. I don't need the points, it's just tidier ;)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have several 9600 PowerMac and an 8100 I can try it on. The next problem is finding the required drivers and an old photoshop.

Comment: I'd ask Adobe about both - they might do it just to know one still exists - amusement value, historical pride...

Comment: @Tetsujin, Adobe is far more interested in getting my money than anything else. They are unbelievably greedy. Even students and instructors aren't spared from their criminal licensing fees.